# Validação formulario jquery

Tags: jquery

Bom estou validando um formulário no serviço, mas estou com algumas dificuldades, estou usando o plugin validate do jquery, vocês conhece uma maneira em jquery mais eficiente e mais atrativa ?

Comment: quais dificuldades? o validate funciona bem, precisa explicar um pouco melhor pra podemos te ajudar

Comment: Assim eu fiz a validação para um formulario usando o validate certo, no formulario que eu validei teria um botão que clicando nele abriria outra pagina para preencher as informações do cadastrante, mas assim não estou conseguindo chamar esta outra pagina  que seria este codigo pessoafisica_validacao: function () {
    $('#frmPessoaF').validate({
        rules: {
            id_PF_Nome: { required: true }
        },
        messages: {
            id_PF_Nome: { required: "Digite o seu nome" }
        },
        wrapper: 'div'
    })

}

Comment: Pelo menos post na pergunta o HTML do formulário.

Comment: como o @LeoCaracciolo comentou, clique no link "editar" logo abaixo da sua pergunta e coloque o `html` e esse código `javascript` na pergunta pra ficar melhor a visualização